# How to read an XML data in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have an XML

```
<Table>
  <Columns>
  <Column Name='Name' Datatype='varchar(100)'/>
  </Columns>
  <Rows>
  <Row Name='Test' Number='123'/>
  </Rows>
</Table>
```

I want to read **Name** value in the provided xml in sql server How Can I do that?

I tried using

```
`Declare @XMl XML 
select @xml= cast(Data as xml) from Table
select y.value('Name[1]','varchar(100)') as Name
@xml.nodes(//Row) as x(y)`
```

but am getting null values as result set How can I acheieve this in sql server

Comment: Please show your full code that you tried

Comment: SQL Server 2012 or 2008? *Both* are **completely** unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```sql
    declare @doc xml = 
    '<Table>
      <Columns>
      <Column Name="Name" Datatype="varchar(100)"/>
      </Columns>
      <Rows>
      <Row Name="Test" Number="123"/>
      </Rows>
    </Table>'
    
    select r.value('@Name', 'varchar(200)') Name
    from @doc.nodes('/Table/Rows/Row') n(r)
```

Comment: Wow it Worked.. Can you explain what is the use of '@Name' ?

Comment: '@' selects attributes rather than elements.  This dates back to XPath.